# doubly linked list in C, overlooks final entry, or wants one where there is none

Tags: c

I have been studying C out of Kochan's Programming in C 4th edition.  I'm trying to strike a balance between bashing my head against a wall for hours and asking for insights.

I am in the chapter on pointers, the exercises have you build a number of functions, then expand to a doubly linked list.  One item is having the list point front to back and back to front.  My issue is that when going from front to back, the last entry displays a value where I want to skip the value.  Same going the other direction.  The methodology I had been using is to have a node entry at the front and back for the sake of being able to add entries to the beginning and end of the list.   Just a note, we have not reached memory allocation or the like.  Also I left in my insert function just in case there is some problem there.  Thanks in advance

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry
  {
      struct entry *previous;
      int      value;
      struct entry *next;
  };

void insertEntry(struct entry *what, struct entry *where)
{
    what->next = where->next;
    what->previous = where->previous;
    where->next = what;
    where->previous = what;
}

void printEntries_Reverse (struct entry initial)
    {
        while (initial.previous != NULL){
            printf("%i  \n", initial.previous->value);
            initial.previous = initial.previous->previous;
        }
    }

void printEntries(struct entry initial)
{
     while (initial.next != NULL){
        printf("%i   \n", initial.next->value);
        initial.next = initial.next->next;
}
printf("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  struct entry head, foot, n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, nx;

  struct entry *list_ptr, *list_end;

  list_ptr = &n0;
  list_end = &n4;

    n1.value = 100;
    n2.value = 200;
    n3.value = 300;
    n4.value = 400;


    n0.next = &n1;
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = &n4;
    n4.next = NULL;


    n0.previous = NULL;
    n1.previous = &n0;
    n2.previous = &n1;
    n3.previous = &n2;
    n4.previous = &n3;

    nx.value = 250;

    insertEntry(&nx, &n2);
    printEntries(*list_ptr);
    printEntries_Reverse(*list_end);

  return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that it looks like the `printEntries` function is actually breaking the list.

The line:
`initial.next = initial.next->next;`
is reassigning the next pointer in each node in the list.

Here's how the first 3 entries look before calling `printEntries`
[image]

After one iteration, these entries look like this:
[image]

I changed the print entries function a little bit to look like this:

```
void printEntries(struct entry *initial)
{
     while (initial != NULL){
        printf("%i   \n", initial->value);
        initial = initial->next;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

The main reason is to iterate through the list without changing any of the pointers that are actually in the list node. It only changes the pointer variable `initial`, not the contents of the list.

---

I know that feeling of bashing your head against the wall though. I used `gdb` to find the bug here, and I'd strongly recommend learning the basics to anyone learning C.

Gdb is pretty intimidating to get into, but 95% of the time, all you ever need to use is the parts in this article up to the "Misc" section https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/

---

Comment: Aw man yea that looks great, I will check it out.  Debugger is a later chapter, but i don't see much wrong with getting into it now.  Am still reviewing your answer above, which takes me forever, sorry and thanks.

Comment: Don't be sorry :) Its hard to learn on your own, and the only way takes time. Good luck!

Comment: it's cleaner, but has the same issue.  from back to front it wants to display the 400, prolly because the list reaches the 400 before it reaches the NULL, and same going the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, thanks to the clarification regarding my list construction, I was able to solve my problem by adding some "IF" statements to test when the entry should be part of the list.

```
void printEntries_Reverse (struct entry *initial)
    {
        if (initial->next == NULL)
            initial = initial->previous;

        while (initial->previous != NULL){
            printf("%i  \n", initial->value);
            initial = initial->previous;
        }
    }

void printEntries(struct entry *initial)
{
    if (initial->previous == NULL)
        initial = initial->next;
     while (initial->next != NULL){
        printf("%i   \n", initial->value);
        initial = initial->next;
}
printf("\n");
}
```